# Spacing issue with lists in Beamer

Tags: beamer, itemize

When I run:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\title{Talk to your statistician early and often}
\author{Peter Flom}
\date{\today}

\frame{\titlepage}

\frame{\frametitle{Table of contents}\tableofcontents}


\section{What goes wrong}
\frame{\frametitle{Introduction}}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Write the analysis section after the proposal is written
  \item Do the analysis after the data is collected
  \item Have the analysis drive the research instead of vice versa
  \item P-ing on the research
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

everything looks fine, but if I run

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\title{Talk to your statistician early and often}
\author{Peter Flom}
\date{\today}

\frame{\titlepage}

\frame{\frametitle{Table of contents}\tableofcontents}


\section{What goes wrong}
\frame{\frametitle{Introduction}}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Write the analysis section after the proposal is written
  \item Do the analysis after the data is collected
  \item Have the analysis drive the research instead of vice versa
  \item P-ing on the research
\end{itemize}


 \subsection{Write the analysis section after the proposal is written}
   \frame{\frametitle{I have a proposal due Tuesday, can you write the analysis section?}}
   \begin{enumerate}
     \item Jan. 2016 - Dr. B, a new postdoc, has an idea for a grant
     \item Feb - Aug 2016 - Dr. B reads the literature (while doing everything else)
     \item Aug 2016 - Dr. B drafts something and shows it to his mentor
     \item Nov 2016 - his mentor replies
     \item Dec 2016 - Dr. B rewrites and sends to lots of people
     \item Jan - Mar 2017 - they reply
     \item Apr 2017 - Dr B writes a 2nd draft and sends it topeople
     \item May - Sep 2017 - they reply
     \item Oct 2017 - Dr. B writes a third draft
     \item Nov 2017 - Nov 2018 - Dr. B looks for good RFPs
     \item Dec 2018 - he finds one, due date : Jan 1. He redrafts it and
     \item Dec 23 2018 - he brings it to me and asks me to write the analysis section.
   \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

then the spacing on the first list (in PDF) is weird, with the items spread out and taking up the whole screen.

How can I fix this?

(Using WinEdt 10.1, MikTeX 2.9 on a Window 10 machine).

Comment: There are many issues. Try working with `\begin{frame} ... \end{frame}`. And use `Dr.\ ` instead of `Dr. `. And so on.

Comment: The problem is indeed that only your frametitles are in frames, not the rest. BTW the syntax `\frame{...}` is deprecated and only works for compatibility reasons, better use the `frame` environenment mentioned by @marmot in his comment above

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: it would be better to have `\title` etc. before `\begin{document}` to help generate meaningful pdf meta data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `\frame` in an inappropriate way. It should cover the full frame contents. Using `\begin{frame}...\end{frame}` is IMHO much more intuitive and helps to avoid such issues.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\title{Talk to your statistician early and often}
\author{Peter Flom}
\date{\today}

\frame{\titlepage}

\frame{\frametitle{Table of contents}\tableofcontents}


\section{What goes wrong}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Introduction}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Write the analysis section after the proposal is written
  \item Do the analysis after the data is collected
  \item Have the analysis drive the research instead of vice versa
  \item P-ing on the research
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\subsection{Write the analysis section after the proposal is written}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{I have a proposal due Tuesday, can you write the analysis section?}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Jan.\ 2016 - Dr.\ B, a new postdoc, has an idea for a grant
  \item Feb - Aug 2016 - Dr.\ B reads the literature (while doing everything else)
  \item Aug 2016 - Dr.\ B drafts something and shows it to his mentor
  \item Nov 2016 - his mentor replies
  \item Dec 2016 - Dr.\ B rewrites and sends to lots of people
  \item Jan - Mar 2017 - they reply
  \item Apr 2017 - Dr B writes a 2nd draft and sends it topeople
  \item May - Sep 2017 - they reply
  \item Oct 2017 - Dr.\ B writes a third draft
  \item Nov 2017 - Nov 2018 - Dr.\ B looks for good RFPs
  \item Dec 2018 - he finds one, due date : Jan 1. He redrafts it and
  \item Dec 23 2018 - he brings it to me and asks me to write the analysis section.
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

The output then becomes

[image]

I added `[t]` to the last two frames to have the contents aligned at the top. In frame 2, there is no such option, and you can see the difference. And I added `\` after `Dr.` and `Jan.` to improve the spacing.

Comment: Thanks! I used to always use frame that way, then I saw it with \frame and thought it would be easier to type.

Comment: @PeterFlom You *could* use frames, too, but then you need to place the closing `}` after the frame contents. I find this very confusing, but this is just an opinion.